# Is Silverlight for Mobile now available?

Tags: silverlight, windows-mobile

Is Silverlight for Mobile now available as of today, April 21, 2010?

Is it supported in Windows Mobile 6 phones? I read that it will only be supported in Windows 7 Phones
http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/02/can-silverlight-save-windows-mobile-from-plummeting-sales.ars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Silverlight for Mobile now available?

It is still in [Community Technical Preview for Windows Phone 7](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/) (as of 21 April 2010) and it is not compatible with Visual Studio 2010 RTM Version. The emulator is supposed to be pretty good so we can develop against it.

> Is it supported in Windows Mobile 6 phones?

It is not available for WM6 (yet). I am not sure with their plan.

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#cite_ref-Chapman_2009_54-1):

> The first [Community Technology Preview (CTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_Technology_Preview) for Windows Mobile 6 was
>   expected in the 2nd Quarter of 2008,
>   but it still not officially announced.
>   Microsoft has stopped focusing on
>   bringing Silverlight to Windows Mobile
>   6.x and is planning to include it in Windows Mobile 7.[[55]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#cite_note-Chapman_2009-54)

Comment: It is not available for WM6 (yet). but it will be?

Comment: @cancelledout: Microsoft has not said yet one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

The Developer Tools can be downloaded [here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/), but there aren't any Windows Phone 7 devices released yet.

Answer (score 0):

Last month I read this blog-article about an "open source clone" of silverlight coming to Iphone. I'm very curious about this

http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/03/14/novell-to-bring-open-source-silverlight-clone-to-iphone/